# Spivak: Interpretation of motivation behind definition $e^x=\exp(x)$.

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, logarithms, exponential-function, inverse-function

I'm going through the chapter about the logarithm and exponential functions in Spivak's *Calculus*.

My question isn't about any particular computation or proof, but rather the following definition

> For any number $x$, $e^x=\exp(x)\tag{1}$

To cut to the chase, is the definition above in effect defining a previously undefined symbol (the symbol $e^x$ when $x$ is irrational)?

To provide more details of what I mean, I need to back up and go through the sequence of concepts presented in the chapter.

The function $\log$ is defined

$$\log{x}=\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt\tag{2}$$

From this definition we can obtain various properties of $\log$, and in particular that it has an inverse $\log^{-1}$. We give this function the name $\exp$, and it has the property

$$\exp (x+y)=\exp (x)\exp (y)\tag{3}$$

Assume that for a number $a$, $a^n$ has been defined if $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

If we restrict a variable $x$ to be rational, using property $(3)$ we can show that

$$\exp(x)=[\exp(1)]^x$$

if we expand our definition of the symbol $a^x$, in a specific way, for the cases where $x$ is a rational but not natural number.

In particular, we define $a^0=1$, $a^{-n}=\frac{1}{a^n}$, $a^{1/n}=\sqrt[n] {a}$, and $a^{m/n}=\sqrt[n]{a^n}$.

At this point, we can compute $\exp(x)$ for rational $x$ if we know what $\exp{1}$ is. This turns out to be a very special number that we name $e$.

Thus for rational $x$, $\exp(x)=e^x$.

What about if $x$ is irrational?

We know that in this case $\exp(x)$ is defined because $(i)$ $\exp$ is continuous because $\log$ is, $(ii)$ $\exp$ is defined everywhere because the image of $\log$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

We just don't know how to compute it.

**So now we reach the point I have a question about.**

Note that at this point in the book, there is no definition of a number raised to an irrational power. For $x$ irrational, the symbols

$$2^\sqrt{2}, 3^\pi, e^\sqrt{10}, e^x$$

are undefined, correct?

The next step that Spivak takes is to simply define one of the undefined symbols.

$(1)$ defines the previously undefined symbol $e^x$ as the value of a function that we know exists.

Perhaps this simple definition seems trivial, but I found it to be one of aspects I most had to think about in this chapter.

It's weird because at this point we have

$$\exp(x)=[\exp(1)]^x$$

for all $x$. For rational $x$, $e^x$ means something independently from $\exp(x)$, but for irrational $x$, $e^x$ is simply defined in terms of $\exp{x}$, which means that even if we were to know exactly what the number $e$ is, it seems we wouldn't be able to compute $e^x$ for irrational $x$.

**Is my interpretation of the definition and its motivation correct?**

A definition of $a^x$ is then given in terms of this new definition of $e^x$

> **Definition:** If $a>0$, then, for any real number $x$,
>
> $$a^x=e^{x\log{a}}$$

and a definition of $\log_a{x}$ is obtained as a sort of consequence of the other definitions.

Comment: I don't know Spivak's book, but as soon as $a^x$ is defined for $x$ rational, it is possible to define $a^x$ where $x$ is irrational, by continuity. That would make more sense (in my opinion) than waiting to first define $\exp(x)$.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni I think your approach is used in an end-of-chapter problem. We are asked to prove that if $f$ is continuous and  $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$ then  either $f=0$ or $f(x)=[f(1)]^x$ for all $x$. We prove the $f\neq 0$ case by showing it is true for all rational numbers, then using a result from a previous chapter: if $f$ and $g$ are continuous, the set $A$ of real numbers is dense, and $\forall x, x\in A\implies f(x)=g(x)$ then $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$.

In our case, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense, $f$ is cont. by assumption, $g(x)=[f(1)]^x=e^{x\log{f(1)}}$ is continuous, and

Comment: as shown in the first part of the proof, $\forall x,x\in\mathbb{Q}\implies f(x)=g(x)$. Therefore, (by the result from a previous chapter) for all $x$ we have $f(x)=[f(1)]^x$.

Comment: Your questions are model examples of How to Provide Context on Mathematics SE.

Comment: The exponential function $exp(z)=e^z$ is an entire function holomorphic over the whole complex plane $z\in\mathbb{C}$, and the Maclaurin series $e^z=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}$ is globally convergent. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html for the more general case $s^z$ where $s,z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

tl; dr: "Yes."

---

I can't speak for Spivak, only for myself, but this is how I prefer to develop elementary transcendental functions when teaching real analysis.

The advantages include establishing that $\exp$ has "nice, expected" properties (as listed in the question) with little additional work beyond what is needed to develop the integral and the derivative.

Just as you say, if $a$ is a positive real and $r = p/q$ is rational, we have an effectively algebraic definition of $a^{r} = a^{p/q}$ as the unique positive real whose $q$th power is $a^{p}$. (Existence and uniqueness of such a number must be proven separately, of course!)

An inductive argument shows
$$
\exp(r) = [\exp(1)]^{r}\quad\text{for all rational $r$,}
$$
and more generally that
$$
\exp(r\log a) = a^{r}\quad\text{for all rational $r$.}
$$
The expression on the left-hand side is defined for all *real* $r$, so it furnishes a reasonable definition of the right-hand side. Since $\exp$ is continuous and strictly increasing, this definition of real exponentiation "behaves as expected," e.g., $a^{x} = \sup \{a^{r} : r < x\}$.

As you say, prior to such a definition, an expression such as $2^{\sqrt{2}}$ or $3^{\pi}$ is undefined. (In fact, $\pi$ itself is undefined at this stage of Spivak if memory serves. Tangentially [heh], in developing the circular functions and defining $\pi$ I prefer to follow Ahlfors, whose power series approach I find cleaner than Spivak's inversion of integrals followed by patching.)

Comment: regarding the last paragraph, at this stage trigonometry has already been introduced :) It's power series which haven't been introduced yet.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks; too many years since I last taught from Spivak. :)

Comment: Indeed $\pi$ is defined as $\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$ in Chapter 15 on Trigonometric Functions. Is there something slightly non-symmetric between the definitions of $e^x$ for rational $x$ (the definitions are the algebraic ones like $e^n=\prod_{i=1}^n e$ and $e^{-1}=\frac{1}{e^n}$, etc) and the definition of $e^x$ for irrational $x$ which is simply $\exp(x)=\log^{-1}{x}$? After all, assuming we know what the number $e$ is, we can compute $e^x$ for rational $x$ by operations of multiplication and division. But how do we compute $e^x$ for irrational $x$?

Comment: IIRC, power series are the tool of choice for numerical evaluation:$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\quad\text{for all real $x$,}$$and there are efficient bounds on the error for a particular partial sum. (Speaking purely of theory, in another universe Spivak might have developed the properties of $\exp$ using power series, analogously to Ahlfors' development of $\cos$ and $\sin$.)

Comment: The question in my previous comment above is asked as a question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504300/is-there-an-asymmetry-between-our-ability-to-compute-ex-for-rational-x-vs-f