# Is there an asymmetry between our ability to compute $e^x$ for rational $x$ vs for irrational $x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, exponential-function, inverse-function

Assume we know the value of the number $e$. Consider the meaning of the symbol

$$e^x$$

If $x$ is rational then

- $e^0$=1
- $e^n=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n e$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$
- $e^{-n}=\frac{1}{e^n}=\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n e}$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$
- $e^{1/n}=\sqrt[n]{e}$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$
- $e^{m/n}=(\sqrt[n]{e})^m$ for $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$

So at least superficially it seems we know what $e^x$ is in terms of other defined operations such as multiplication, division,  and n-th root.

Now, if $x$ is irrational then $e^x$ is defined as

$$e^x=\exp(x)=\log^{-1}(x)$$

So to compute, for example $e^{\sqrt{2}}$ we would need to figure out what

$$\log^{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

is.

Is there an actual asymmetry between our ability to compute $e^x$ for rational $x$ vs for irrational $x$ or is this impression incorrect?

EDIT: I not looking for a way using series. I am following the book *Calculus* by Spivak. So far limits, continuity, derivatives, integrals, the fundamental theorem of calculus, trigonometric integrals, and exponential and logarithm functions have been covered. Series is still a few chapters aways.

Comment: What about computing $e^x$ as $1+x+\frac12x^2+\frac1{3!}x^3+\frac1{4!}x^4+\cdots$?

Comment: You can compute both with a power series and in practice computing integer roots is gonna use some iterative method that isn't in terms of complexity different from a power series.

Comment: For irrational $x=\log 2$ computing $e^x$ is very easy :) I think the answer to your question comes down to what you mean by "compute". As others have pointed out you can get arbitrary precision using power series methods.

Comment: What sources/references are you learning from?  Most of your "rational x" identities seem to me to apply not only to integer inputs, but rational inputs, and real inputs as well. (Other than the specific problem of $e^{m/n}$ not working at precisely $n=0$.)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I'm following Spivak's Calculus and haven't reached sequences/series yet.

Comment: @Stefan Perhaps I use the word compute incorrectly. What I mean is: given certain known concepts, we can express a particular new concept using the known concepts. Series isn't one of the known concepts at this point in the book I am following. It just seems strange the way that $e^x$ was defined for irrational $x$. It was simply defined to be the value of $\exp(x)$, which itself is the inverse of $\log$ which actually is defined as something already known: an integral. Since I'm not sure how to invert an integral, it is bothering me how I would actually express $e^x$ in this case.

Comment: What is the definition of $e^x$ (if you want to define it as $\log^{-1} (x)$, then what is the definition of $\log$)? The ones I know either use Taylor series or defines it via continuity (i.e. $\lim e^{q_i}$, where $q_i$ are rational and $q_i \to x$). So you don't have a nice way of computation since you don't have nice definition in the first place. The computation methods based on these two definitions were mentioned above.

Comment: @AmateurDotCounter Calculus by Michael Spivak. If $x$ is any real number, the function $\exp$ has the property that $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$. In the case of rational $x$ and $y$, the individual terms $\exp(x)=e^x$ and $\exp(y)=e^y$ have the meanings I expressed above in my original post. In the case of, say, $x$ being irrational, the only thing I know to say about $\exp(x)$ is that it is $\log^{-1}(x)$. I don't know how to obtain the inverse of an integral, which is how $\log$ is defined. So how do I express $e^x$ in this case?

Comment: @Dmitry $\log(x)$ is defined $\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt$

Comment: Well it depends what you mean by compute. As long as you've shown that the inverse of the integral exists using say intermediate value theorem and showing that log is unbounded, then it exists and it is a valid definition. You can probably show a lot of properties of e^x using this inverse integral definition. Maybe you take issue with the fact that it's not written in a specific "closed" form, but consider that a lot of closed forms are short hand for an infinite computation, for instance sqrt(x), so these forms aren't any easier to compute a priori than an inverse integral

Comment: @latbbltes Yes I think what I am taking issue with is something along the lines of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

> So at least superficially it seems we know what $e^x$ is in terms of other defined operations such as multiplication, division, and n-th root.

This isn't quite right; these identities don't help us "solve for $e$" they "depend on $e$".  In much the same way that the following identities "depend on $2$":
$$
2^0=1\\
2^n=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n 2 \quad \mbox{for $n\in\mathbb{N}$}\\
2^{-x}=\frac{1}{2^x}\\
2^{1/n}=(\sqrt[n]{2})    \quad \mbox{for $n\in\mathbb{N}$}\\
2^{m/n}=(\sqrt[n]{2})^m   \quad \mbox{for $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$}\\
$$

This is because the identity $a^{(x+y)}=a^x a^y$ is valid for any $a\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ and so you can derive both the $e^{(x+y)}=e^x e^y$ identity (which you mention in the comments) as well as a $2^{(x+y)}=2^x2^y$ identity (which is probably the simplest non-trivial example).

---

All of the identities you mention (and all of the ones I mention) can basically be derived from the basic $a^{(x+y)}=a^x a^y$ starting point.

If $x=x$ and $y=0$ then:
$$
2^{(x+0)}=2^{x}2^{0} \quad \rightarrow \quad 2^{0}=1
$$
If you consider $x=n-1$ and $y=1$, then you can see that there is essentially an repeatable "pull out $2^1$" process that you can apply until $n$ is fully sperated:
$$
2^{n}=2^{(n-1)}2^{1} \quad \rightarrow \quad 2^{n}=\underbrace{2^{1}2^{1}2^{1}...2^{1}}_{n}
$$

And the exact same sorts of derivations can be done starting from the $e^{(x+y)}=e^x e^y$ identity (in fact I'd be surprised if those derivations don't show up either in the textbook or its exercises).

Basically, your book is trying to get you comfortable manipulating equations that look like $e^{3+x}=e^{6x^2}$ in much the same way that you might already be able to handle something like $2^{3+x}=2^{6x^2}$.  In the end, that'll usually mean shuffling things around until you can finally get to something like $2^{3+x-6x^2}=2^{0}$... but where do you go from there?

Assuming this is a basic "solve for x" kind of problem we'd ideally like to keep simplifying the problem and getting x by itself.  And this is where Logarithms come into play as they can actually allow us to further simplify equations like the one above.  The Binary Logarithm (of x) is a function with the property:
$$ 
\log_2(2^x)=x
$$
which means that we can take our expression $2^{3+x-6x^2}=2^{0}$ and "take the binary logarithm of" both sides (just as we'd "subtract two" from both sides, or "multiply by y" both sides, or "exponentiate to the power 3" on both sides).
$$ 
\log_2(2^{3+x-6x^2})=\log_2(2^0) \quad \rightarrow \quad {3+x-6x^2} = 0
$$
from which you can rearrange and solve the quadratic equation for x.

The Natural Logarithm is just the $e$-version (compared to the above 2-version) that does the same kind of operation:
$$ 
\log_e(e^x)=x
$$
which we can write a few different ways according to that three-way definition at the end of your question:
$$ 
\log_e(e^x)=x\\
\log_e(\ \exp(x) \ )=x\\
\log_e( \ \log^{-1}_e(x) \ )=x\\
$$
Which is to say... that we have another tool (logarithms) that allow us to do a new kind of manipulation to equations beyond just the old add/subtract, multiply/divide, and exponentiation that we are more familiar with.